# How to prove this equation about derivatives?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I'm currently studying derivatives, and I saw some equations but this one just not seems much trivial to me: $$\lim_{h\to 0}\left(\frac{f\left(x_0-2h\right)-f\left(x_0+3h\right)}{h}\right) = -5\,f'\left(x_0\right)$$

So far i just try to do some arithmetic job and got this:
$$
\begin{align*}
\lim_{h\to 0}\left(\frac{f\left(x_0-2h\right)-f\left(x_0+3h\right)}{h}\right)
&= \lim_{h\to \:0}\left(\frac{f\left(x_0-2h\right)-f\left(x_0\right)+f\left(x_0\right)-f\left(x_0+3h\right)}{h}\right)\\
&=\lim_{h\to 0}\left(\frac{f\left(x_0-2h\right)-f\left(x_0\right)}{h}\right)+\lim_{h\to 0}\left(\frac{f\left(x_0\right)-f\left(x_0+3h\right)}{h}\right)
\end{align*}$$

But from here i know it must be $\lim \:_{h\to \:0}\left(\frac{f\left(x_0-2h\right)-f\left(x_0\right)}{h}\right)\:=-2f\:'\left(x_0\right)$ and $\lim \:_{h\to \:0}\left(\frac{f\left(x_0\right)-f\left(x_0+3h\right)}{h}\right)\:\:\:=\:-3f\:'\:\left(x_0\right)$, but i don't know how to prove this two. tnx!

Comment: write $f(x_0-2h) - f(x_0 + 3h) = (f(x_0-2h) -f(x_0)) + (f(x_0) - f(x_0 + 3h))$

Comment: @abel is what i wrote in my attempts..

Answer (score 1):

Note that, for example,
$$
\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(x_0) - f(x_0 + 3h)}{h} = 
-3 \cdot \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(x_0 + 3h) - f(x_0)}{3h}
$$
And we can also write (setting $\alpha = 3h$)
$$
\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(x_0 + 3h) - f(x_0)}{3h} = 
\lim_{\alpha \to 0} \frac{f(x_0 + \alpha) - f(x_0)}{\alpha} = f'(x_0)
$$

Comment: this is not even a hint.

Comment: "Take the limit as $3h \to 0$". Does that make it a hint?

Answer (score 0):

$$f'(x_0)=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{f(x_0-2h)-f(x_0+3h)}{(x_0-2h)-(x_0+3h)}=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{f(x_0-2h)-f(x_0+3h)}{-5h}$$
$$=-\frac{1}{5}\lim_{h\to0}\frac{f(x_0-2h)-f(x_0+3h)}{h}$$
$$\implies \lim_{h\to0}\frac{f(x_0-2h)-f(x_0+3h)}{h}=-5f'(x_0)$$

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @kingW3 it's not an answer, but  very strong hint that basically gives the answer away. If you insist though, I'll modify the post.